# How do I install all python site-packages into a single location instead of using venv?

Tags: python

I want all my `pip` package to go to one and only one location on my Windows 11 Pro laptop computer: %PROGRAMFILES%\Python311\Lib\site-packages\

I don't need or want multiple version of Python and packages on my computer taking up extra room.

At the moment I'm seeing the following places that have a `site-packages` directory:

1. %PROGRAMFILES%\Python311\Lib\site-packages
2. C:\projects\python<name of project>\venv\Lib\site-packages
3. %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python311\lib\site-packages

I know that many will recommend using individual /venv/ directories per python project, but that creates a mess with duplicate libraries scattered all over the place making a ***huge mess of my hard drive***.

I'm willing to accept the consequences to older projects after I install a newer version of some package, such as `toga` in what I'll call the ***single version of the truth*** location of python packages.

I have full Administrator privileges on my own laptop so I don't care if I have to perform every `python -m pip install whatever` as Administrator.  It's worth it to me to prevent duplicate packages.

So, my question boils down to this: under Windows 11, do I need to install ***every*** package `as Administrator` to avoid all the duplicate packages?

Reference PowerShell Script (run as Administrator):

```
Set-Variable -Name 'dateFormat'-Value 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' -Option Constant
Get-Date -Format $dateFormat
[string] $outFile = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath 'site-packages.txt'
Remove-Item -Path $outFile -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$dt = Get-Date -Format $dateFormat
Write-Verbose $dt
$dt | Out-File -FilePath $outFile
Set-Location -LiteralPath 'c:\'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\' -Recurse -Force -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  Where-Object { $_.FullName -like '*site-packages*'} | 
  Format-Table FullName |
  Out-File $outFile -Append
Get-Date -Format $dateFormat
```